# how to convert a long long int to a string w/o sprintf

Tags: c

how can i convert a long long int to a string without sprintf
i tried making an itoa function that would work with long long valuse but it didn't worked. this function worked with int but doesn't work with long long. why?

```
char *ft_itoa(long long int n)
{
    char *c;
    int x;

    x = 0;
    if (!(c = (char*)malloc(how_long_n(n) + 1)))/*divides n with 10 until is 0 to get its lenght*/
        return (NULL);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        x = 1;
        n = -n;
    }
    c = reverse_int_char(n);/*converts reversed number into a string*/
    c = reverse_that_char(c);/*reverses the string*/
    if (x == 1)
        get_neg(c);/*gets the sign*/
    return (c);
}
```

Comment: Please post `how_long_n()`, is it still taking `int`? And `n == -0`? Seriously, what did you mean with that?

Comment: reverse_int_char and how_long_n take long long too sry about the -0 thing i have a program that test my functions and it has wierd tests

Comment: 1. Where is the problem? `n` gets wrong value? the int to string fails? or the reversing? please check the return values. 2. How does `char *` func returns: return `("0\0")`, do you mean `NULL`?

Comment: the problem is probably in the conversion when i convert the int to char x[i]=n % 10 + '0'

Comment: print\debug and give us the answer. I guess you want an answer that is right and not probably right.

Comment: giving INT_MIN goes well but giving INT_MIN - 1 gives me MAX_INT

Comment: You lose the allocated memory here `c = reverse_int_char(n);`. Perhaps you wanted to use `strcpy` there?

Comment: still not working

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work depends entirely on your implementations of `how_long_n`, `reverse_int_char`, `reverse_that_char` and ofcourse the way that it fails. (Do you see an incorrect string, segfault, empty string etc.) To get help please post all the code including what went wrong